# String format specifier handling float variable

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
def to_celsius(self):
     """Fahrenheit to Celsius"""

     fah = float(self.ent_fahrenheit.get())
     cel = (5 / 9) * (fah - 32)

     tkMessageBox.showinfo("Fahrenheit To Celsius",
             "%s deg F is equal to %.2f deg C" % (fah, cel))
```

I have a Python 2 code snippet using Tkinter to display a simple message box.

I am wondering if it is okay that the format specifier %s is handling (receiving) a float value from variable fah?

It seems like it is because I am not encountering any error of some sort when I ran the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `%s` is fine, but is still the equivalent of calling `str()` on the object. If you want to be able to specify float width and precision then you should use one of the float specifiers (e, E, f, F, g, G) instead.